# In Ruby. How do I refer to the class from within class << self definition?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby. How do I refer to a class from within the class << self definition?

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    puts self # returns MyModule::MyClass

    class << self
      puts self # returns #<Class:MyModule::MyClass>
      puts ???
    end
  end
end
```

How do I get the result MyModule::MyClass from where the ??? is?

Thanks,
Arth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until somebody comes up with a more orthodox solution, [nesting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting) seems to do the work:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    class << self
      puts nesting[1] # MyModule::MyClass
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to do the trick! Interested to know if there are any other solutions as well though.